# Error Create Foreign Key SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

```
CREATE TABLE Usuario 
( 
    id int identity not null, 
    usuario char(20) unique not null, 
    senha char(10) not null, 
    tipo_usuario char(15) not null, 

    primary key (id),  
    foreign key (tipo_usuario) references TpoUsuario 
       on update cascade on delete set default
);

CREATE TABLE TpoUsuario 
( 
    id int identity not null,  
    tipo_usuario char(15) not null, 
    primary key(id) 
);
```

This use a codes to top, and received this message error.

First I created table `TpoUsuario`, then I created table `Usuario`.

> Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Column 'TpoUsuario.id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Usuario.tipo_usuario' in foreign key 'FK__Usuario__tipo_us__60A75C0F'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Read the error message. The data types are not matching - you're trying to create a foreign key on TpoUsuario.id (i think you don't want to use they column) and Usuario.tipo_usuario.

Comment: I'm Used Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: SSMS is your client tool, your DBMS would be something like SQL Server 2008 R2, Oracle 11, MySQL, etc.

Comment: Yes, is a Sql Server 2008

Comment: Sorry for ignorance, i am learning database in moment, just a little knowlegde

Answer (score 3):

TpoUsuario.id is an int data type column while Usuario.tipo_usuario is char type column 
Could you link Usuario.id with TpoUsuario.id or Usuario.usario with TpoUsuario.tipo_usuario

Comment: Or, depending on the actual data in that source, change the data type of the CHAR() column to INT ...

Answer (score 0):

See how to define foreign-keys:

[SQL FOREIGN KEY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

You say

```
foreign key  (tipo_usuario)  references TpoUsuario  on update cascade on delete set default
```

Syntax is `FOREIGN KEY (column col1, column col2, ...) REFERENCES table_name(column col1, column col2,...)`